# how can i get month and year from custom formated datetime in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get month and year from this datetime format in form of number of month.

My datetime formate is `19 August 2015 - 10:50 am`.

How can I get this?

Comment: please clarify your question,do you want to get no of months from the given date time eg in your case from your datetime the no of months would be 2.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have a MySQL Varchar field that contains a custom string like '19 August 2015 - 10:50 am' that represents a date, you can get the date value with this:

```
SELECT str_to_date(customdate, '%c %M %Y - %h:%i %p') as date_column
FROM yourtable
```

Please see the [str_to_date function documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), and the [list of available date formats](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Then you can just use [MONTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) and [YEAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) functions:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(str_to_date(customdate, '%c %M %Y - %h:%i %p')) AS year,
  MONTH(str_to_date(customdate, '%c %M %Y - %h:%i %p')) AS month
FROM
  tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

Will there always be a hyphen (`-`) in your date? Then, we have to remove it first by using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
$date = "19 August 2015 - 10:50 am"; /* YOUR GIVEN EXAMPLE */
$date = str_replace("-", "", $date); /* REMOVE HYPHEN */
$date = date("m Y", strtotime($date)); /* 08 2015 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Us this

```
<?php

//date_default_timezone_get('Asia/Colombo');

$date = '19 August 2015 - 10:50 am';

echo date("Y/m", strtotime($date)); //2015/08
echo date("Y-m", strtotime($date)); // 2015-08

?>
```